# Anybody help to develop windows phone app in VS2012 with sencha and cordova

Tags: extjs, visual-studio-2012, cordova

I need to develop a windows mobile app using sencha+cordova with VS2012. I am not able to find out any tutorial or article or anything that can help me to develop the windows mobile app. 
Please help.
Thanks
Ashutosh

Comment: This question is too open. Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). You can start with the [getting start guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/getting_started) @ Sencha.com.

Answer (score 0):

As A1rPun said, to get going you should start following the [Getting Started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides) guides on the Cordova site. Specifically, if you look at the getting started for [Windows Phone 8](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone%208) and Step 2 in particular, it will tell you how to install the Visual Studio templates that will allow you to create a new project type that is configured to use Cordova.

Alternatively, you can check out some of the services that make this a little easier to get started doing Cordova development inside VS. Full disclosure that I work for this team, but [Nomad for Visual Studio](http://vsnomad.com) is designed to get you up and going developing a Cordova app inside VS within about 3 minutes of download, without needing to install any SDKs or do any configuration.